# Toshiba L645D dead touchpad on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, touchpad, synaptics, toshiba-satellite

(The problem seems to have appeared after a recent 17.10 update. Touchpad has been working on 17.10 previously.)

Touchpad on Toshiba L645D is unresponsive, but USB mouse is OK.  Touchpad OK under Windows 10.

```
$ synclient
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ grep synap /var/log/syslog
Feb 19 07:14:37 martin-toshiba kernel: [    3.981941] psmouse serio4: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5686], y [..4786]
Feb 19 07:14:37 martin-toshiba kernel: [    4.041672] psmouse serio4: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04771/0xa40000/0xa0000/0x0, board id: 0, fw id: 590211
Feb 19 07:14:37 martin-toshiba kernel: [    4.041680] psmouse serio4: synaptics: Toshiba Satellite L645D detected, limiting rate to 40pps.
Feb 19 08:54:02 martin-toshiba kernel: [    3.970528] psmouse serio4: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5686], y [..4786]
Feb 19 08:54:02 martin-toshiba kernel: [    4.030559] psmouse serio4: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04771/0xa40000/0xa0000/0x0, board id: 0, fw id: 590211
Feb 19 08:54:02 martin-toshiba kernel: [    4.030566] psmouse serio4: synaptics: Toshiba Satellite L645D detected, limiting rate to 40pps.
Feb 19 08:55:41 martin-toshiba fwupd[2548]: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug synapticsmst: MST firmware updating not supported by OEM
```

Suggestions?  TIA!